# Error "connect: connection refused" trying to fullfill acme challenge

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I am pretty new to k8s and currently I am trying to set up a K8s-Cluster on a baremetal server with a publix IP.
However during the validation process letsencrypt cannot access the cluster. After following the [trouble shooting](https://cert-manager.io/docs/faq/acme/) I could find the following error: "Connection refused"

I set up my cluster with kubespray

K8s version: v1.22.4

**Cert-Manager**:

```
kubectl create namespace cert-manager
kubectl label namespace cert-manager certmanager.k8s.io/disable-validation=true
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.5.4/cert-manager.yaml
```

**Nginx-Ingress-Controller**:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/v1.0.4/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

**ClusterIssuer**:

```
  ---
  apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
  kind: ClusterIssuer
  metadata:
    name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
    #namespace: cert-manager
    namespace: default
  spec:
    acme:
      server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      email: dav@my-company.com
      privateKeySecretRef:
        name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key
      solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class:  nginx
```

Certificate.yml:

```
  ---
  apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
  kind: Certificate
  metadata:
    name: example-app
    namespace: default
    #namespace: cert-manager
  spec:
    dnsNames:
      - {real-dns}.com
    secretName: example-app-tls
    issuerRef:
      name: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
      #name: letsencrypt-staging
      kind: ClusterIssuer
```

After running kubectl get all -n default, i got

```
root@node1:~# kubectl get all -n default
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/cm-acme-http-solver-2vx5w   1/1     Running   0          8s

NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/cm-acme-http-solver-gp2f6   NodePort    10.233.13.8   <none>        8089:30158/TCP   8s
service/kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.233.0.1    <none>        4
```

I think maybe the cert-manager could not create an issuer for the service cm-acme-http-solver-gp2f6?
Can someone plase give me a hint, how can I solve the problem?
Many thanks in advance.

Edit:

There is also debug step I tried:

clusterissuer:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl describe clusterissuer letsencrypt-cluster- 
issuer
Name:         letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
Namespace:    
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         ClusterIssuer
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-12-16T17:35:30Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:acme:
          .:
          f:email:
          f:privateKeySecretRef:
            .:
            f:name:
          f:server:
          f:solvers:
    Manager:      OpenAPI-Generator
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2021-12-16T17:35:30Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:acme:
          .:
          f:lastRegisteredEmail:
          f:uri:
        f:conditions:
    Manager:         controller
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-12-16T17:35:31Z
  Resource Version:  230199
  UID:               95d183fb-c50e-49ed-83fb-98ceee0f1b7a
Spec:
  Acme:
    Email:            ###@###.com
    Preferred Chain:  
    Private Key Secret Ref:
      Name:  letsencrypt-cluster-issuer-key
    Server:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    Solvers:
      http01:
        Ingress:
          Class:  nginx
Status:
  Acme:
    Last Registered Email:  trang@my-company.com
    Uri:                    https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/322624000
Conditions:
  Last Transition Time:  2021-12-16T17:35:31Z
    Message:               The ACME account was registered with the 
ACME server
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                ACMEAccountRegistered
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

CertificateRequest:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl describe CertificateRequest example-app-w59ng
Name:         example-app-w59ng
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/certificate-name: example-app
              cert-manager.io/certificate-revision: 1
              cert-manager.io/private-key-secret-name: example-app-qddzv
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         CertificateRequest
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-12-22T14:07:00Z
  Generate Name:       example-app-
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:conditions:
    Manager:    controller
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2021-12-22T14:07:00Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           cert-manager.io/v1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Certificate
    Name:                  example-app
    UID:                   5c47b8a9-c076-4387-b117-bb4b1864448d
  Resource Version:        1520892
  UID:                     2fe3875a-4b4d-4139-bef4-820679f8356e
Spec:
  Extra:
    authentication.kubernetes.io/pod-name:
      cert-manager-7c6f78c46d-8r9n7
    authentication.kubernetes.io/pod-uid:
      5f7638e9-27e8-4a3f-b149-96e9a88d0c74
  Groups:
    system:serviceaccounts
    system:serviceaccounts:cert-manager
    system:authenticated
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:    ClusterIssuer
    Name:    letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
  Request:   [...]
  UID:       8dfc1be6-2e0b-4a2e-8087-a274110c4b74
  Username:  system:serviceaccount:cert-manager:cert-manager
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2021-12-22T14:07:00Z
    Message:               Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
    Reason:                cert-manager.io
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Approved
    Last Transition Time:  2021-12-22T14:07:00Z
    Message:               Waiting on certificate issuance from order default/example-app-w59ng-1045993216: "pending"
    Reason:                Pending
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type    Reason           Age    From          Message
  ----    ------           ----   ----          -------
  Normal  cert-manager.io  4m42s  cert-manager  Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
  Normal  OrderCreated     4m42s  cert-manager  Created Order resource default/example-app-w59ng-1045993216
```

Order:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl describe order example-app-w59ng-1045993216
Name:         example-app-w59ng-1045993216
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/certificate-name: example-app
              cert-manager.io/certificate-revision: 1
              cert-manager.io/private-key-secret-name: example-app-qddzv
API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Order
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-12-22T14:07:00Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:finalizeURL:
        f:state:
        f:url:
    Manager:      controller
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2021-12-22T14:07:00Z
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:authorizations:
    Manager:    controller
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2021-12-22T14:07:00Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           cert-manager.io/v1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  CertificateRequest
    Name:                  example-app-w59ng
    UID:                   2fe3875a-4b4d-4139-bef4-820679f8356e
  Resource Version:        1520893
  UID:                     4bb32a01-71ee-43ce-976d-072a718fcc98
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    ###.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:   ClusterIssuer
    Name:   letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
  Request:  [...]
Status:
  Authorizations:
    Challenges:
      Token:        rloCCUdQXQx_r9idENjxwXBfPn0DpJ7S8f5Ca5YTZzs
      Type:         http-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/58799104090/PllHuQ
      Token:        rloCCUdQXQx_r9idENjxwXBfPn0DpJ7S8f5Ca5YTZzs
      Type:         dns-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/58799104090/AYdl0A
      Token:        rloCCUdQXQx_r9idENjxwXBfPn0DpJ7S8f5Ca5YTZzs
      Type:         tls-alpn-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/58799104090/DRK6xg
    Identifier:     cranberry-soft.de
    Initial State:  pending
    URL:            https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/58799104090
    Wildcard:       false
  Finalize URL:     https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/finalize/322624000/47528833830
  State:            pending
  URL:              https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/322624000/47528833830
Events:
  Type    Reason   Age   From          Message
  ----    ------   ----  ----          -------
  Normal  Created  21m   cert-manager  Created Challenge resource "example-app-w59ng-1045993216-247428591" for domain "###.com"
```

Challenge:

```
root@node1:~# kubectl describe Challenge example-app-w59ng-1045993216-247428591
Name:         example-app-w59ng-1045993216-247428591
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Challenge
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-12-22T14:07:01Z
  Finalizers:
    finalizer.acme.cert-manager.io
  Generation:  1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:presented:
    Manager:      controller
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2021-12-22T14:07:02Z
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:reason:
    Manager:    controller
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2021-12-22T14:07:02Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Order
    Name:                  example-app-w59ng-1045993216
    UID:                   4bb32a01-71ee-43ce-976d-072a718fcc98
  Resource Version:        1520918
  UID:                     4cde9b13-e7af-4fbb-ac60-b25e977108a3
Spec:
  Authorization URL:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/58799104090
  Dns Name:           ###.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:  ClusterIssuer
    Name:  letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
  Key:     [...]
  Solver:
    http01:
      Ingress:
        Class:  nginx
  Token:        [...]
  Type:         HTTP-01
  URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/58799104090/PllHuQ
  Wildcard:     false
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://###.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/rloCCUdQXQx_r9idENjxwXBfPn0DpJ7S8f5Ca5YTZzs': Get "http://###.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/rloCCUdQXQx_r9idENjxwXBfPn0DpJ7S8f5Ca5YTZzs": dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:80: connect: connection refused
  State:       pending
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From          Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----          -------
  Normal  Started    29m   cert-manager  Challenge scheduled for processing
  Normal  Presented  29m   cert-manager  Presented challenge using HTTP-01 challenge mechanism
```

Comment: provide verbosity logs

Comment: Hi @Vit, I edited my question and provided the logs i ve got

Comment: many thanks, ill take a look

Comment: I have to thank you :)